# Running dir against multiple directories

Tags: windows, cmd, dir

If I run, for example:

```
dir /s /b /o:gn "c:\Program Files\TrueCrypt" | findstr .sys
```

I comfortably get

```
c:\Program Files\TrueCrypt\truecrypt.sys
c:\Program Files\TrueCrypt\truecrypt-x64.sys
```

..in return.  But if I **add** a folder that doesn't exist (I won't go into the reasons why this would be the case, but it will be), I just get an error:

```
dir /s /b /o:gn "c:\Program Files\TrueCrypt" "c:\non folder\non subfolder" | findstr .sys
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Unlike in the UNIX world where I can use "find" and it returns files found in any directories without only barfing on the directories that don't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a loop and call `dir` for each of the folders:

```
for %F in ("c:\Program Files\TrueCrypt" "c:\non folder\non subfolder") do (
  dir /s /b /o:gn "%F"
) | findstr .sys
```

However, depending on what you need exactly you can probably do better by ditching `dir` and `findstr` here and opt for a loop over the files. But that depends a bit on what your overall goal is.

Comment: Perfect...well...almost!  I think you meant to put a "%F" in there after the dir command.  Ta

Comment: Well, yes. Sorry. I rarely bother to test my batch stuff anymore these days, so minor slips like those happen sometimes :)